# Activity Create and resume again and again in Nougat Version

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I am navigating from `Activity A` to `Activity B` without finishing `Activity A` (because i want to go back on it and have some variables values).

In `Activity B` I launch camera and save captured image but the problem is, after capture camera the `Activity A` is re-create and resumed, causing re initialization of my variables.

How to stop it?

**Note:** The problem occurs only in Nougat Version.

Comment: How possible!!! only Nougat version????

Comment: Can you post some code on how exactly you are calling the Activity B and how you are navigating back from B to A? Also you said this happens only on Nougat, You tested on other versions and the code worked ok?

Comment: Yes, I tested on all older version, works perfect. Just only way to go in Activity A by calling finish() method. Any body know? In nougat version they stop other activities for better performance ?

Comment: Please post code

Comment: Are you changing orientation of phone while capturing image?

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to know here is about the complete activity life cycle. Basically to summerize them they are 
OnCreate, - called when activity is created
OnStart,  - called when activity starts
 OnREsume,  - when activity gets back
OnPause,  - when activity is overlapped
OnStop,   - when activity is closes
and onDestroy  - when finish() is called.

Though you have not mentioned how you started an activity and got back to the same activity, the correct way to get back to previous activity is by calling

```
finish()
```

on camera activity.
I guess you have got back to activity A by using

```
Intent i= new Intent(this, ActvityA.class)
startActivity(i)
```

which is the the correct way to do.
Just call the finish() when you want to get back to Activity A from B (Here B is in top of A).

Additional
If you want to pass data from activity B to A, just put something called as `Intent Extra or Bundle`

Comment: I am not calling Activity A from Activity B. I just call after capture image, finish()

Comment: if you have called finish after capture , once you have captured image the activity in stack is A. Thats why you are redirected on Activity A's onResume and I am sure same will happen with all version of android.pls share code

Answer (score 0):

> Activity A is create again and resume, so my variables are initialize again. How to stop it.

Yes that is normal. First rule with Android programming is that your activity can be killed at any time. So to not loose your variables you have to save them at the right moment.

You would do that to override `onSaveInstanceState()` putting your variables in the bundle.

Then you can retrieve them in `onCreate()` from the function parameter.